# Apply a function to multiple columns of a SparkDataFrame, at once

Tags: r, databricks, lapply, sparkr

In basic R, this is how I apply a function to multiple columns at once, using `data.table` :

```
d <- data.table(V1 = rep(1:2, 4:3), V2 = c(1, 2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4), V3 = 1:7, V4 = sample(letters, 7))
Cols <- c("V2", "V3")
d[, (Cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) x * 100), .SDcols = Cols]
```

But now,  I'm trying to replicate the same on a SparkDataFrame, in Azure Databricks with `SparkR`.

I looked on the side of `dapply, ...`, of `spark.lapply`, but I can't figure out how to apply a same function to several columns of a SparkDataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the column names as a list using `SparkR::colnames` function, and then use `base::lapply` on that list. Note that the function argument inside `lapply` has to use the columns as a Spark column object (`SparkR::column`). Example below:

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c(1:3), v2 = c(3:5), v3 = c(8:10))
sdf <- SparkR::createDataFrame(df)
cols <- SparkR::colnames(sdf)
modify_cols <- c("v2", "v3")
spark_cols_new <- lapply(cols, function(x) { 
    if (!x %in% modify_cols){
      SparkR::column(x)
    } else {
      SparkR::alias(SparkR::column(x) * SparkR::lit(100), x)
    }
})
sdf_new <- SparkR::select(sdf, spark_cols_new)
```

Note that, if you intend to use a constant then it can be provided directly instead of using `SparkR::lit` function as well, but it is a safer choice.

Comment: Explanations + example = a very big step for me. Especially the concept of columns and the way they should be used. Thank you very much !