# How to use an undefined list of variables as column names in a SparkDataFrame with SparkR?

Tags: r, databricks, azure-databricks, sparkr

I keep progressing in the world of `SparkR`, and I am now facing an issue which I am unable to resolve.

Working on SparkDataFrame manipulations, I may want to update some columns, or aggregate others. I learned how to do it on a case-by-case basis, i.e. column by column.

Let's take an example :

```
library(SparkR)
library(magrittr)

# Creating SDF
nb.row <- 10 
nb.col <- 10 
m <- matrix(runif(n=nb.row*nb.col, min = 0, max = 100), nb.row, nb.col)
sdf <- createDataFrame(data.frame(ID = 1:10, CODE = base::sample(LETTERS[1:2]), V = m))
```

1. If I want to update columns I can do something like :

```
sdf <- withColumn(sdf, "V_1", sdf$V_1 * 1000)
sdf <- withColumn(sdf, "V_2", sdf$V_2 * 1000)
```

2. If I want to aggregate columns I can do something like :

```
agg1 <- agg(groupBy(sdf, "CODE"), "SV_6" = sum(sdf$V_6), "SV_7" = sum(sdf$V_7))
```

**My question is :** how to deal with these cases when I don't know the list of columns I want to work on ? (Easy on R basic, this seems insurmountable to me in SparkR...)

1. Back on the case of *updating*. I found something like :

```
list.var.1 <- paste0("V_", 1:5)
for (i in 1:length(list.var.1)) {
  sdf <- withColumn(sdf, list.var.1[i], sdf[[list.var.1[i]]] * 1000)
}
```

This gives me the expected result, but is it the simplest script ? Nothing lighter or more "official" ?

2. Back on the case of *aggregation*. I found something like :

```
# Useful functions
DFjoin <- function(left_df, right_df, key = "key", join_type = "left"){
    left_df <- withColumnRenamed(left_df, key, "left_key")
    right_df <- withColumnRenamed(right_df, key, "right_key")
    result <- join(
        left_df, right_df,
        left_df$left_key == right_df$right_key,
        joinType = join_type)
    result <- withColumnRenamed(result, "left_key", key)
    result$right_key <- NULL
    return(result)
}

sum_spark <- function(res, df, gb, col) {
  Cols <- paste0('S', col)
  tmp <- agg(groupBy(df, gb), alias(sum(df[[col]]), Cols))
  result <- DFjoin(res, tmp, "CODE")
}

# First step to create base SDF called res
res <- SparkR::select(sdf, sdf$CODE) %>% SparkR::distinct()

# Updating res in a for loop with join
for (i in 1:length(list.var.2)){
  res <- sum_spark(res, sdf, "CODE", list.var.2[i])
}
```

This also gives me the expected result, but the script really seems heavy (according to me, versus R basic). Am I wrong ?

I can't find any more information on this. So everything helps !!

Comment: This question is not clear, what exactly are you looking for? As a general suggestion, try using `lapply` (analogous to Python's list comprehension) along with other SparkR functions.

Comment: I am pretty familiar with ```lapply``` in R basic, but I don't know why, I have trouble using it in SparkR...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70786884/9689416) on how to use lapply in conjunction with other SparkR functions to get what you desire instead of using `for loops`.

Sharing one useful function for using `SparkR::agg` on a list of columns below that will serve your purpose:

```
#' Apply SparkR aggregate function on list of columns
#'
#' This function acts as a boilerplate for simplifying the code to do
#' aggregation on multiple columns as a list and apply Spark::agg function on
#' that.
#'
#' @param spark_df Spark dataframe (Grouped or ususal) on which some SparkR
#'     aggregate function to be applied
#' @param agg_cols_list List of Spark column object having some aggregate
#'     function
#'
#' @examples \dontrun{
#'   # sdf is a SparkR dataframe having numeric columns "a" & "b"
#'   sdf <- SparkR::createDataFrame(data.frame(a = c(1, 2), b = c(1, 5)))
#'   sparkr_agg_listargs(sdf,
#'     lapply(c("a", "b"), function(x) sum(SparkR::column(x)))
#'   )
#' }
sparkr_agg_listargs <- function(spark_df, agg_cols_list) {
  do.call(SparkR::agg, c(spark_df, agg_cols_list))
}
```

Please use `SparkR::alias` effectively to get desired names of new columns.

Comment: Yeah, I just saw that answer you're referring to. This is you answering another question from ...... me ! Looks very useful to me !

Comment: Very useful function! Gives me the expected result. But i have trouble understanding how it works. Why ```do.call``` inside a function? I don't have the whole working of SparkR in mind I guess ...

Comment: `do.call` is used because the function `SparkR::agg` expects all the aggregate function over columns to be passed as arguments, like `SparkR::agg(sdf, SparkR::avg(sdf$mpg), sum(sdf$hp), SparkR::avg(sdf$wt))`. But the problem here is we cannot pass a list of new aggregated columns like `SparkR::agg(sdf, list_of_agg_cols)` -- this can be tackled using `base::do.call` function which takes a function name and a list of arguments to be passed to that function as arguments!

Comment: To add a ```groupBy```, I first create GroupedData, like ```gb.sdf <- groupBy(sdf, "CODE")```, then ```lapply```ing the function on gb.sdf instead of sdf. It seems to work. But does a more concise writing exist ?

Comment: Nope, you may use `%>%` operator to do everything in single step of assignment.